# Case insensitive matching in Rails .where() clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code:

```
Test.all.where("comment like '%test%'")
```

How can I write this to include all models where `Test.comment is like '%test%'`, but ignore the case of `test`. `Test`, `Testing`, and `TEST` should all be returned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't care about changing database (it should be valid sql by the way), you can do something like this:

```
Comment.where("LOWER(comments.comment) LIKE LOWER('%test%')")
```

If you do care about database portability, I suggest you this (arel only):

```
comments = Comment.arel_table
Comment.where(comments[:comment].matches("%test%"))
```

Consider that the second one will ignore case up to version XXX but I don't remember which version. If you are using Rails 3.2.x or Rails 4 you are fine (tested in both).

**SQL Output example**
With previous arel code, output in PostgreSQL is the following one:

```sql
SELECT comments.* FROM comments WHERE (comments.comment ILIKE '%test%')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Test.all.where("comment ilike '%test%'")
```

fetches all matching case-insensitive results of test, which is what you want.

Comment: Underrated answer! Rightly fetches all matching case-insensitive results.